# Button to share/post predefined comment on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

On our site, we use the twitter tweet-button to have users post "This site is awesome! #siteName". Now we want something similar, for Facebook. Not just to share the page, but to actually *preset the user comment* that goes above. How can we do this?

-We can probably not use a customised 'share' button, only accepts url/description/... for a page preview, not the actual *user comment that goes above*.

-Maybe we could cook up another solution using the Facebook Comment plugin? Somehow use javascript to enter the automatically predefined message in the text field, and check the 'post on facebook'?

I have no idea if this is possible, but would be very grateful for an answer!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Pretty sure you can’t do that anymore using any pre-existing API. If you want to post content on behalf of the user, you can do that, but that involves creating an app and making users to authorize the app the first time they’re using it (probably not worth the effort due to the high level of friction introduced). In short, you can’t dictate what the user can share in a Facebook post using their common API.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is

- not allowed according to the [Facebook policy](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill/) - prefilling the message/comment is not allowed.
- not possible, because you cannot prefill the Share Dialog